# How to build TS types via vue-tsc (not component types but pure TS files)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have `tsconfig.build-types.json` where I explicitly set one file to be included in the build:

```
{
  "include": ["src/types.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.cy.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/__tests__/**/*"]
}
```

Then I run

`vue-tsc --project tsconfig.build-types.json --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist/types`

And I can't see /dist folder created.

The `types.d.ts` file contains:

```
export interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

How to get this interface exported into dist folder?

The whole process works for building vue components, where I get /dist/type/index.d.ts that hold all of my components definitions (in the case when I set  `"include": ["src/**/*"],`).

But I want to keep my custom TS types in a separate file, not in Vue components, because sometimes you might need to provide a custom type that is not used in .vue files.

What is not correct in this build process so that it doesn't catch types.d.ts definitions?